# Which route in the WP REST API do I access data passed into register_setting()?

Tags: rest-api

For example:

```
    $args = array(
    'type'              => 'string',
    'description'       => '',
    'sanitize_callback' => null,
    'show_in_rest'      => true
);

//Job Board Settings Info
register_setting( 'jobboard-settings', 'company_name', $args );
```

I have trouble figuring out which route these are exposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Settings are accessible through the [Settings endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/):

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/settings
```

Comment: It returns a different object though
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/#schema

Comment: Different to what?

Comment: i was expecting i would see a key like 'jobboard-settings' or a key-value pair of 'company_name: $input_value'

Comment: Have you saved any values for this setting yet?

Comment: yes, and i can extract the data with get_option just fine

Comment: if it helps, i only do basic authentication, if that affects anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to `register_setting()` in both `admin_init` & `rest_api_init` hooks in order to get your setting through `wp/v2/settings` REST API endpoint.

Had the same issue and found the solution [in this blog post](https://coreysalzano.com/wordpress/using-register_setting-and-the-rest-api/) to save me